# как oтправить форму, которая находится на другом веб-сайте

Tags: php, ajax, form

На другом сайте есть одна страница, которая содержит форму, которая отправляет запрос ajax. Я хочу создать PHP-скрипт, который заполнит эту форму и отправит запрос, а затем получит ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть AJAX запроса в том, что он посылает на определенный url заданным методом (post или get) заданные параметры. Поэтому просто посмотрите какие параметры нужны и передавайте их на эту страницу тем же методом. Для передачи используйте curl.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            http_build_query(array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2')));

// Получаем ответ ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```